# XStream - use previous serialized object after adding a function to the interface?

Tags: java, xml-serialization, xstream

I use XStream to serialize an object "A" implementing an interface :

```
interface MyInterface { 
       String functionA();
}

MyInterface a = new MyInterface() {...}
```

Now the interface changed , and I added another function:

```
interface MyInterface {
       String functionA();
       String functionB();
}
```

Trying to deserialize it now fails (with the listed exception), because the interface changed - But can I make it work somehow?

This is the exception:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: com.cf.TestSaveSerialization$1 : com.cf.TestSaveSerialization$1
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:68)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:71)
```

I've looked at the [XStream FAQ](http://xstream.codehaus.org/faq.html#Serialization_newer_class_versions) , but there's nothing about changing functions. Any idea?

Comment: I can't imagine why XSTream cares what methods you implement. It doesn't have a serial version like Java Serialization does.  What is the exact error message?

Comment: @Peter , it's an interesting remark - I assumed it will failed even before writing the test. Wouldn't the implemented functions change the serialization of the object?  I've added the exception to the post

Comment: This is looking for the first anonymous in TestSaveSerialization.  By serialising an anonymous class, you will have an issue adding or removing, or changing the order of anonymous classes in case it changes the generated number for the class.

Comment: @Peter thanks , I'll run the test using a regular class!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds more like there's an issue with the anonymous class, rather than XStream or the serialization mechanism itself. Are these the actual signatures? Have you tried altering the signature of a named class (a non-anonymous class)?

Comment: I've tried serializing and deserializing an antonymous class before I introduced the change the API and it worked fine , but I'll try doing it with a concrete one

Comment: You can only create instances of concrete classes. An anonymous class is a concrete class. What you need is a named class so it won't change name on you accidentally.